# Use symbols to pass a class member's name?

Tags: dart, symbols

I'm writing a testing utility function and would like to pass a class member *name* and get its value. Could I use `Symbol`s for this? My test code looks like this

```
class Foo {
  String a = 'A';
  String b = 'B';
  static void output(Symbol symbol) {
    debugPrint("The value is '$symbol'");
  }
}

Foo.output(#a);
```

I'm trying to get a result like `The value is 'A'` but I'm getting `The value is 'Symbol("a")'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the value of something *by name*, where the name is a *value*, and *at runtime*, that is reflection.
You need `dart:mirrors` for that, which isn't available on most platforms.

Better yet, don't do it at all. Dart has first class functions, so you can pass in a function accessing the variable instead:

```dart
class Foo {
  String a = 'A';
  String b = 'B';
  static void output(String read(Foo value)) {
    debugPrint("The value is '${read(this)}'");
  }
}

void main() {
  var foo = Foo();
  foo.output((f) => f.a);
  foo.output((f) => f.b);
}
```